# При проигрывании аудио чтобы был элемент

Tags: javascript, html

Хочу на сайте добавить возможность по окончанию воспроизведения аудио был добавлен элемент кнопки `<a href="connected.html">Вход на сайт</a>` с помощью JavaScript или HTML

```html
<script>
function playSound(sound) {
  var song = document.getElementById(sound);
  song.volume = 1;
  if (song.paused) {
    song.play();
  } else {
    song.pause();
  }
}
</script>
<li><audio id="sound"><source src="http://samirkon12.neonarod.com/audio/dialup.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<input type="submit" value="Вызов" id="button" class="button" onclick="playSound('sound');""></li>
```

заранее спасибо

Comment: в аудио есть атрибут `controls` — для отображения кнопок

Comment: мне чтобы после воспроизведения появилась кнопка, а не управления треков, или я ничего не понял

Comment: кнопка чего? формулируйте точно вопрос иначе его заминусуют `добавить возвожность при воспроизведении аудио`

Comment: кнопка <a href="connected.html">Вход на сайт</a>

Comment: `onended` — событие завершение проигрывания звука

Comment: тег **type** в **audio** не применяется, только в **source** внутри audio: `<source type='audio/mpeg'></source>`.

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял задачу:

```js
var callAudio = new Audio(); // Создаём аудио
callAudio.src = 'https://minov.pw/_remote/ruso/audio-1.mp3'; // Передаём ссылку
callAudio.volume = '.25'; // Чтобы не пугать людей..
callAudio.load(); // Предварительно загружаем.

document.querySelector('#js-call').addEventListener('click', function(e) { // Вешаем событие на нажатие
  e.preventDefault(); // Останавливаем переход по ссылке
    
  callAudio.play(); // Запускаем аудио
  callAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() { // Выполняем что-то по окончанию аудио
    alert('- Да, алло?');
  });

  return false;
})
```

```html
<a id="js-call" href="#">Вызов</a>
```

Comment: точнее так: включаю музыку, музыка закончилась и остановилась, и идёт переход на сайт, или как в JavaScript сделать переход на другой сайт

Comment: @The_WhO, вот там где алерт выводится, добавьте переход на другой сайт. `location.href = 'https://google.com/'`

Comment: спасибо! помогло!